# Collision Management in a Simulation with Discrete Motion

Tags: time, simulation, collision, event-simulation

I am building a simulation in which items (like chess pieces) move on a discrete set of positions that do not follow a sequence (like positions on a chessboard) according to a schedule.

Each `position` can hold only one `item` at any given time. The schedule could ask multiple `item`s to move at the same time. If the destination `position` is occupied, the scheduled movement is cancelled.

**Here is the question**: if `item A` and `item B`, originally situated at `position 1` and `position 2` respectively, are scheduled to move simultaneously to their next positions `position 2` and `position 3`, **how do I *make sure* that `item A` gets to `position 2`, hopefully in an efficient design?**

**The reason to ask** this question is that naively I would check whether `position 2` is being occupied for `item 1` to move into. If the check happens before `item B` is moved out of the way, `item 1` would not move while in fact it should. Because the positions do not follow a sequence, it is not obvious which one to check first. You could imagine things gets messy if many items want to move at the same time. In the extreme case, a full chessboard of items should be allowed to move/rearrange themselves but the naive check may not be able to facilitate that.

Is there a common practice to handle such "nonexistent collision"? Ideas and references are all welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two researchers, Ahmed Al Rowaei and Arnold Buss, [published a paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5679045) in 2010 investigating the impact that using discrete time steps has on model accuracy/fidelity when the real-world system is event-based. There was also some [follow-on work](https://documents.pub/document/wsc11-paper.html) in 2011 with their colleague Stephen Lieberman. A major finding was that if you use time stepped models, order of execution matters and can cause the models to deviate from real-world behaviors in significant ways. Time-stepped models generally require you to introduce tie-breaking logic which doesn't exist in the real system. Logic that is needed for the model but doesn't exist in reality is called a "modeling artifact," and can lead to increased model complexity and inaccuracies. Systematic collision resolution schemes can lead to systematic biases.

Their recommendation was to build models based on continuous time. Events are scheduled using the actual (continuous) event times, which determine the order of event execution as in the real-world system. This occasionally (but rarely) requires priority tie breaking based on event type, so that (for example) departure events occur before arrival events if both were to occur at the exact same time.

If you insist on sticking with time-stepped models, a different strategy is to use two or more passes at each time step. The first pass lays out the desired state transitions and identifies potential conflicts, the last pass applies the actual transitions after conflicts have been resolved. The resolution process might be do-able in the initial setup pass, or may require additional passes if it's sufficiently complex.

Comment: The solution I came up with is exactly the one you presented in your last paragraph! But obviously your discussion is more comprehensive!

I agree with the rest of your discussion, and as food for thought, 1) sometimes time-stepped models could reflect real life as conflicts and ambiguities do exist in real life, so basically the conflict resolution in the simulation has already the resolution policy in place; 2) tightly packed moving sequence of items such as an assembly line may still be well addressed by your solution in the last paragraph, but yes it can be costly if something breaks!

Comment: @G.Z. At the end of the day, it's the modeler who decides whether the model is "good enough" or not. I thought the linked papers are interesting, because Al Rowaei (who was a PhD student at the time) had some examples where the outcomes of the simulation could be wildly different depending on which time advance model you used. Also note that discrete event scheduling is a superset of time-stepped modeling because you can always schedule periodic update events. It's impossible to go the other way, because once you discretize time there's no generalizable way to return to continuous time.

Comment: @G.Z. Anyway, interesting question (at least to me!) so thanks for prompting me to go back and squirt some WD-40 onto the neurons to de-rust them.